# Android Recording Videos: Find out when user taps recording button

Tags: android

I created a very simple Application, where I start a video recording with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

So far everything works fine, and the video-screen appears with the recording-button and everything else. Now, I'm interested if it is possible to find out the time when a user taps on the recording button.

I am new to Android, but I imagine a solution where it may be possible to put a Tap-Listener or something else on this button. Unfortunately googling arround gave me no useful results.

Has someone of you an idea, how this could be realized, or if it maybe is not possible to do this?

Kind regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I'm interested if it is possible to find out the time when a user taps on the recording button.

That is not possible. There may not be a recording button. If there is, it is in another app, not yours.

> I imagine a solution where it may be possible to put a Tap-Listener or something else on this button

No, because that is not your button. It is not in your process. And it may not exist, as not all camera apps have to use a button to trigger video recording.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was hoping, that this would be also possible with the build in camera-app.

Comment: @Stefan: There are dozens, if not hundreds, of "build in camera-apps". Device manufacturers usually have their own, and perhaps several of them across device models.